# javascript remove no id/class images from no id/class DIV element

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to 'adjust' some site (which is not mine) to my needs by creating a greasemonkey script which will use some javascript codes. I already searched stackoverflow and other places, but coudn't find the solution to this specific problem. And the problem is that there are some  links inside a DIV elment which doens't have an ID or Class attached to it, so I can't use 'getElement(s)By'(Id, ClassName or TagName). And I can't use getElementsByTagName because I can't figureout how to remove these specific images since I don't want to remove all the images from the  of the page (for instnace, first IMG in the document is needed to stay visible).
Here I simplified the page source code:

```
<body class="someclass">
    <div id="instructions">
        <img src="http://somesite.com/s7ad7sg/ds67sgs/2ys7s.jpg" alt="resized  image">
    </div>

    <form id="some_form_id">
        <div id="not_important"></div>

        <div id="now_what">
            <div=id="here_we_go">
                <div>(some content here)</div>

                <div>
                    some random text which is not between any tags

                    <img src="http://somesite.com/subfolder/subfolder/26256.jpg" alt="resized image2">
                    <img src="http://somesite.com/subfolder/subfolder/33633.jpg" alt="resized image2">
                    <img src="http://somesite.com/subfolder/subfolder/98461.jpg" alt="resized image2">
                    <img src="http://somesite.com/subfolder/subfolder/38746.jpg" alt="resized image2">
                    <img src="http://somesite.com/subfolder/subfolder/08456.jpg" alt="resized image2">
                </div>


                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

^ So, I need to remove these:

26256.jpg
33633.jpg
98461.jpg
38746.jpg
08456.jpg

^ How to remove them when they don't have any class or ID attached to them, and also their parent DIV doesn't have any class or ID?

Anyone knows how to do this by using javascript (keep in mind that first image in the  (at the top of the code) needs to stay visible. Also there is a text (which is not inside

tags) above these 5 images which sais "some random text which is not between any tags". That text needs to stay, so I can't cimply remove whole DIV which holds everything. Nameless DIV needs to stay with only that text as part of it.

Thanks in advance!

(again, I don't own the site, so I can't change the html source code by editing it)

**EDIT:**
Thanks everyone for trying to help me! I've tested all your suggestions. Maybe because I'm just a noob, but only one piece of code worked. It's the 2nd method provided by **CertainPerformance**:

```
document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('style'))
  .textContent = '#here_we_go img { display: none; }';
```

^ So that one worked. I don't know why the first method didn't work.

I also kept searching at google, and I've have found some other code examples which I 'adjusted' and tested, so this one also work:

```
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('#here_we_go img'), i;
for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; ++i) {
  imgs[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: you can first get the div by getElementById or class. then get all images url of that div. then use if condition. if image url is `26256.jpg 33633.jpg` then display none that image tag of that div

Comment: Can you give clearer whats the logic you want? Remove all except 1st one, remove by image name only or just random? How the script determine it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getElementsBy* methods return HTMLCollections, which can be difficult to work with. Consider using querySelectorAll instead, which returns a static NodeList - unlike an HTMLCollection, it can be iterated over directly, it won't change while it's being iterated over, and it's much more flexible.

Like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#here_we_go img')
  .forEach((img) => img.remove());
```

That will select all `img`s which are eventual descendants of the `here_we_go` div, and remove them from the DOM.

Another method is to hide them with CSS instead:

```
document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('style'))
  .textContent = '#here_we_go img { display: none; }';
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason 1st method didn't work, but 2nd one does work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.querySelectorAll` and pass in the selector for those images, which would be `document.querySelectorAll('#here_we_go>div>img')`

Answer (score 0):

first get the images src by this

```
var someimage = document.getElementById('here_we_go');
var myimg = someimage.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
var mysrc = myimg.src;
```

Now if `mysrc == 26256.jpg` then make this image display none.

Answer (score 0):

In jquery:

```
$("img:nth-of-type(2)").remove();
$("img:nth-of-type(3)").remove();
$("img:nth-of-type(4)").remove();
$("img:nth-of-type(5)").remove();
$("img:nth-of-type(6)").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Target the nearest parent element with id and use `querySelectorAll` to get all the `img`.Use `forEach` to iterate and `remove` to remove the element

```js
let getImgs = document.getElementById('here_we_go')
  .querySelectorAll('img')
  .forEach(function(item) {
    item.remove();
  })
```

```html
<body class="someclass">
  <div id="instructions">
    <img src="http://somesite.com/s7ad7sg/ds67sgs/2ys7s.jpg" alt="resized  image">
  </div>

  <form id="some_form_id">
    <div id="not_important"></div>

    <div id="now_what">
      <div id="here_we_go">
        <div>(some content here)</div>

        <div>
          some random text which is not between any tags

          <img src="http://somesite.com/subfolder/subfolder/26256.jpg" alt="resized image2">
          <img src="http://somesite.com/subfolder/subfolder/33633.jpg" alt="resized image2">
          <img src="http://somesite.com/subfolder/subfolder/98461.jpg" alt="resized image2">
          <img src="http://somesite.com/subfolder/subfolder/38746.jpg" alt="resized image2">
          <img src="http://somesite.com/subfolder/subfolder/08456.jpg" alt="resized image2">
        </div>


        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```